# Al iniciar una VPN el cliente de Outlook se desconecta a través de Exchange 2019

Tags: servidor, email, outlook, exchangewebservices

Para trabajar con algunas funcionalidades necesitamos conectarnos a una VPN.

Cuando nos conectamos a la VPN el cliente de outlook deja de conectarse a la cuenta de exchange, y hasta que no se desactiva la VPN no envía ni recibe ningún correo.

Usamos Office 2019 y un servidor de correo con Exchange 2019.

Pruebas realizadas:

Con la VPN conectada podemos entrar al correo web a traves de los siguientes enlaces: https://servidorcorreo.dominio.local/owa y https://servidorcorreo.dominio.es/owa

En el cliente de Outlook funciona un correo que trabaja por Office 365 y no por exchange.

Se ha desactivado el antivirus del equipo cliente y sigue sin funcionar.

¿Se puede haber cambiado alguna configuración del servidor de correo al actualizarse y por eso no dejar que funcione? Ya que los problemas vienen desde que actualizamos y reiniciamos todos los servidores, pero solo sucede al activarse la VPN.

Comment: La VPN podria estar agregando nuevas rutas a las PCs y eso genere conflicto. La VPN tambien podria imponer otro DNS, depende de que cliente de VPN usen y la configuracion que tenga.